# Getting error -"Undefined. Implement with the following snippet" when executing protractor cucumber typescript feature file

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am using protractor typescript and cucumber for automation - I have read some articles and added feature file and step definition in my e2e project-

feature file:

Feature: Homepage

```
  Scenario: Visit Homepage
    Given I am on the homepage
    Then I should see a "navbar"
    And I should see a "login" link
    And I should see a "register" link
```

Steps Definition as below :

```
var pc = require('protractor-cucumber');    module.exports = steps; var steps = function() {
     this.Given('I am on the homepage', function (callback) {
    support.get(this, 'http://localhost:5000', function(result){
      setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    });   });

      this.Then('I should see a {stringInDoubleQuotes}', function (link, callback) {
    support.findByBinding(this, link, function(result){
      result.getText().then (function(text){
        text.trim().toLowerCase().should.equal(link.trim().toLowerCase());
        setTimeout(callback, 1000);
      });
    });   });
     };
```

my Support.ts as below -

```
var support = require('../support');
var Support = function(){
};

Support.prototype.get = function(sut, url, callback){
  sut.browser.get(url).then(function(result) {
    callback(result)
  });
};

Support.prototype.findByBinding = function(sut, item, callback){
  sut.browser.findElement(sut.by.binding(item)).then(function(result) {
    callback(result);
  });
};

Support.prototype.isElementPresent = function(sut, find, callback){
  sut.browser.isElementPresent(sut.by.linkText(find)).then(function(result) {
     callback(result)
  });
};

Support.prototype.isElementPresentByClass = function(sut, find, callback){
  sut.browser.isElementPresent(sut.by.css('.'+find)).then(function(result) {
     callback(result)
  });
};

module.exports = new Support();
```

my Protractor.conf.js as below-

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  autoStartStopServer: true,

  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: "chrome"
    }
  ],

  directConnect: false,
  baseUrl: "example.com",
  seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",

  framework: "custom",
  frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),
  //specs: ["./e2e/**/*.feature"],
  specs: ["./e2e/**/*google.feature"],

  // cucumber command line options
  cucumberOpts: {
    //require: "./e2e/**/*.steps.ts",
    require: "Google.steps.ts",
    tags: [],
    strict: true,
    format: ["pretty"],
    "dry-run": false,
    compiler: []
  },

  onPrepare() {
    browser
      .manage()
      .window()
      .maximize();
  }
};
```

my package.json as below-

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "browserstack-local": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cucumber-tsflow": "^2.2.0",
    "domino": "2.0.1",
    "jasmine-bail-fast": "0.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "pretty-bytes": "^5.0.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/chai-as-promised": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/cucumber": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "cucumber": "^2.3.1",
    "grunt-protractor-cucumber-html-report": "^0.2.8",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^1.10.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "protractor-cucumber": "^0.1.8",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^3.1.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Exact Error after when i run command Protractor Protractor.conf.js

> ```
> C:\Source\ClientApp>protractor protractor.conf.js
> (node:11828) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
> [13:06:14] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
> [13:06:14] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
> Feature: Homepage
>
>   Scenario: Visit Homepage
>   ? Given I am on the homepage
>   ? Then I should see a "navbar"
>   ? And I should see a "login" link
>   ? And I should see a "register" link
>
> Warnings:
>
> 1) Scenario: Visit Homepage - e2e\Feature\google.feature:3
>    Step: Given I am on the homepage - e2e\Feature\google.feature:4
>    Message:
>      Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:
>
>        Given('I am on the homepage', function (callback) {
>          // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
>          callback(null, 'pending');
>        });
>
> 2) Scenario: Visit Homepage - e2e\Feature\google.feature:3
>    Step: Then I should see a "navbar" - e2e\Feature\google.feature:5
>    Message:
>      Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:
>
>        Then('I should see a {stringInDoubleQuotes}', function (stringInDoubleQuotes, callback) {
>          // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
>          callback(null, 'pending');
>        });
>
> 3) Scenario: Visit Homepage - e2e\Feature\google.feature:3
>    Step: And I should see a "login" link - e2e\Feature\google.feature:6
>    Message:
>      Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:
>
>        Then('I should see a {stringInDoubleQuotes} link', function (stringInDoubleQuotes, callback) {
>          // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
>          callback(null, 'pending');
>        });
>
> 4) Scenario: Visit Homepage - e2e\Feature\google.feature:3
>    Step: And I should see a "register" link - e2e\Feature\google.feature:7
>    Message:
>      Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:
>
>        Then('I should see a {stringInDoubleQuotes} link', function (stringInDoubleQuotes, callback) {
>          // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
>          callback(null, 'pending');
>        });
>
> 1 scenario (1 undefined)
> 4 steps (4 undefined)
> 0m00.000s
> [13:06:20] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
> [13:06:20] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
> [13:06:20] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
> [13:06:20] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your cucumberOpts:

`//Your step definition file name
require: ["Google.steps.ts", "StepsDefinition.steps.ts"]`

Answer (score 0):

As I may say, you are using wrong dependencies / versions. You are also using `protractor-cucumber` which is not maintained anymore.

I created a boilerplate a while ago that might help, but keep in mind that that the versions are also not updated to the latest versions of for example Cucumber (still on CucumberJS 3). You can find it here https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-cucumber-typescript-boilerplate

Comment: what i understood from above link is i have to install all latest version for all you mentioned in link. But then i don't understand -1. how to write feature file. 2. how to generate step definition 3. how to bind steps & feature 4. where html report will be saved for that plug in

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
this.Given('I am on the homepage', function (callback)
```

To this

```
this.Given(/^I am on the homepage$/, function (callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to write the definition of call in a different js file and it worked for me.